# How to make ng-bind-html compile angularjs code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web

I am working with angularjs 1.2.0-rc.3. I'd like to include html code into a template dynamically. For that I use in the controller :

```
html = "<div>hello</div>";
$scope.unicTabContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
```

In the template I got :

```
<div id="unicTab" ng-bind-html="unicTabContent"></div>
```

It works fine for regular html code. But when I try to put angular template it is not interpreted, it is just included in the page. For example I'd like to include :

```
<div ng-controller="formCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in content" ng-init="init()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, that is not exactly how angular wants to work.  If you want to add html dynamically, look into the `$complie` service.

Comment: why do not you use ngScript to create the about template and then use an ng-include,ng-src to add it

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**This solution doesn't use hardcoded templates, and you can compile Angular expressions embedded within an API response.**

---

**Step 1.** 
Install this directive: https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile

**Step 2.** Include the directive in the module.

```
angular.module("app", ["angular-bind-html-compile"])
```

**Step 3.** Use the directive in the template:

```
<div bind-html-compile="letterTemplate.content"></div>
```

**Result:**

Controller Object

```
 $scope.letter = { user: { name: "John"}}
```

JSON Response

```
{ "letterTemplate":[
    { content: "<span>Dear {{letter.user.name}},</span>" }
]}
```

HTML Output =

```
<div bind-html-compile="letterTemplate.content"> 
   <span>Dear John,</span>
</div>
```

---

For reference sake, here's the relevant directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var module = angular.module('angular-bind-html-compile', []);

    module.directive('bindHtmlCompile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlCompile);
                }, function (value) {
                    element.html(value);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
}());
```

Comment: This jsfiddle helps illustrate the compiling difference between `ng-bind-html` and `bind-html-compile`: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14557/

Comment: I think I hit this question three different times before I realized how simply this would solve my issue.  I'd upvote it twice if I could.

Answer (score 19):

This is what I've made, no idea if it's *the angular way*<sup><sup><sub>TM</sub></sup></sup>, but it works and is super simple;

```js
.directive('dynamic', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
                $compile(element.html(html).contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

So;

```html
<div id="unicTab" dynamic="unicTabContent"></div>
```

---

Edit: **I found the angular way**, and it's *super* simple.

```js
$templateCache.put('unicTabContent', $sce.trustAsHtml(html));
```

```html
<div id="unicTab" ng-include="'unicTabContent'"></div>
```

Don't need to make your own directives or anything.
But it's a bind-once sort of deal, [it wont see changes made to your html](http://jsfiddle.net/yrwd2t5j/11/) like [the custom directive does](http://jsfiddle.net/6wk0pm97/1/).

Comment: I find this answer is the easiest to implement.

Comment: hey why use $watch here? why not just replace the element with the compiled  content? thanks btw.

Comment: so that if the variable changes, that change will be reflected in the DOM on the next `digest`. If your variable would never change you can simplify this, sure, but whenever I put an answer up I try to keep it as generic and universally applicable as possible. For my specific case I think my variable was empty when the directive gets evaluated so I needed the `watch` for when the variable does eventually get populated.

Comment: This worked much better for me! Especially if you are using a filter with the element as well, then this is definitely the way to go. I get a digest limit reached if using the angular-bind -html-compile thing

Comment: Any way I can make the ng-html-compile conditional? I mean attach/assign the directive only on a certain condition like - Grid row click and behave normally otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

As Vinod Louis says in his comment, the best way to do that was to use templates. I had to define a template outside of the regular code, for example I added that code inside of my index.html :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="unic_tab_template.html">
    <div ng-switch on="page">
        <div ng-switch-when="home"><p>{{home}}</p></div>
        <div ng-switch-when="form">
            <div ng-controller="formCtrl">
                <div ng-repeat="item in content">{{item.name}}:{{item.value}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-default>an error accured</div>
    </div>
</script>
```

This template is conditional, so depending on the value of $scope.page, it switches between the 3 templates (the third being an error handler). To use it I had :

```
<div id="unicTab" ng-controller="unicTabCtrl">
    <div ng-include="'unic_tab_template.html'"></div>
</div>
```

That way my page changes depending on the $scope inside of my unicTabCtrl controller.

To conclude the idea of inserting angularsjs template seams to be difficult to realize ($compile seams to be the solution, but I wasn't able to make it work). But instead you may use conditional templating.

Comment: I like this solution, but it would have been better if we could see a sample where the HTML is coming from somewhere else (remote JSON for example and thus not hard coded in the project).

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same thing and came across this module.

http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-html-compile

I just included it and then I was able to use "ng-html-compile" instead of "ng-bind-html"

Answer (score 2):

My solution to similar problem in my current app without using template (not elegant, but working):

```
directive('ngBindHtmlCompile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttributes, transcludeFn) {
            return function postLink(scope, element, attributes) {
                scope.$watch(function() {
                    return scope.$eval(attributes.ngBindHtml);
                }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    $compile(element.children())(scope);
                });
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

It requires `ngBindHtml` on the same element and compiles the element content after it changes with `ngBindHtml`.

```
<div id="unicTab" ng-bind-html="unicTabContent" ng-bind-html-compile></div>
```

`ng-html-compile` looks similar but at first glance it won't be recalculated when the template content is changing. But I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

One way is use a directive for purpose of inserting custom templates that include angular expresssions

```
<div id="unicTab" unic-tab-content></div>
```

```js
app.directive("unicTabContent",function(){
   return {
      restrict:"A",
      template:'{{unicTabContent}}'
   }
})
```

Comment: I like this idea, and it does include the code, but it is still not compiled.

Comment: works fine here as is  http://plnkr.co/edit/sUOxHBUYIdQlAiM3Dy0V?p=preview  Perhaps you have some nested directives or something else causing it not to work

Comment: But I'd like it to compile the code in the variable that you called test. For exemple [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9c50iy?p=preview) display the <div> and </div>, which is not what I'd like.

Comment: OK..can do it with `link` callback of directive  [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GRAfrI?p=preview)

Comment: Indeed it compile html, but not the angular statements. In [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X9vpcd?p=preview) when the test variable is directly injected the ng-click method is connected, but when injected using the directive it isn't.

Comment: several compile techniques can be used.... you keep adding to the initial question...why didn't you outline what you needed from the start? Why wouldn't you just use a directive template, rather than creating angular html in scope??? Suggest you explain your needs in more detail...as well as why you are using approach you are using and not using angular mehtodology

Answer (score 0):

The code below is much simpler using Angular's built-in $interpolate and $sce objects. First inject the $interpolate and $sce Angular objects into your directive as you do anything custom you need in your directive.

```
amqApp.directive('myDir', ['$interpolate', '$sce', function ($interpolate,$sce ) {...}
```

Then create all your scoped variables found in your imported html expressions...

```
$scope.custom = 'Hello World';
```

Next use $interpolate to process your custom HTML and its expressions...then make sure you use the $sce object to trust it as HTML before binding...

```
var html = $interpolate('<b>{{custom}}</b>')($scope);    
$scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
```

Finally, in your view, just make sure use an element with the "ng-bind" or "ng-bind-html" on it in your view display. I found the $sce piece wont display the HTML as HTML (sees it as text) if you don't bind it in your html template like this...

```
<span ng-bind-html="data"></span>
```

You should see in bold...

**Hello World**

I used this trick to import in text/HTML with custom angular {{expressions}} from a web.config.

Answer (score 0):

A lot simplified solution of @clement-roblot based on built-in templates.

Controller:

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$templateCache',
    function ($scope, $templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put('test.html', '2 + 2 = {{ 2 + 2 }}');
    }
]);
```

View:

```
<div ng-include="'test.html'"></div>
```