# AngularJS: embedding angular expressions in database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 database tables, **letters** and **letterTemplates** with an Angularjs frontend.

In letterTemplates.content column, I have a html template with an embedded angular expression like so:

```
<p> Dear {{letter.user.name}},</p>
```

And in the letters preview, I display the letterTemplate.content like so:

```
<div ng-bind-html="letterTemplate.content"></div>
```

which returns the following output:

```
Dear {{letter.user.name}},
```

How do I get the Angular expression to execute?

---

The solutions outlined in [How to make ng-bind-html compile angularjs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726179/how-to-make-ng-bind-html-compile-angularjs-code) relied on using hardcoded Angular templates, whereas I need to parse html and angular statements from an API response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make ng-bind-html compile angularjs code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726179/how-to-make-ng-bind-html-compile-angularjs-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got it to work:

**Step 1.** 
Install this directive: https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile

**Step 2.** Include the directive in the module.

```
angular.module("app", ["angular-bind-html-compile"])
```

**Step 3.** Use the directive in the template:

```
<div bind-html-compile="letterTemplate.content"></div>
```

Output =

```
Dear John,
```

---

For reference sake, here's the relevant directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var module = angular.module('angular-bind-html-compile', []);

    module.directive('bindHtmlCompile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlCompile);
                }, function (value) {
                    element.html(value);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
}());
```