# Angular JS Bind Variable with Directive as Content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application I have a  which I am using to keep a log of events.

It is currently using ng-sanatize as such:

```
<div ng-bind-html="{{eventLog}}></div>
```

This works great. I am able to pre-pend **eventLog** with a HTML message and have it output in the div.

I would like to upgrade this div to allow me to pass in directive that I am using to show a full event trace in another area of the application.

```
anEvent = { type: "Event", message: "A long event message" }    

<logEvent event="{{anEvent}}"></logEvent>
```

Which outputs

```
<div class="event">Event</div>
<div class="message">A long event message</div>
```

I thought that I should be able to simply write

```
eventLog = "<logEvent event=\"' + customEvent + '\"></logEvent>"
```

or even

```
eventLog = "<logEvent event=\"{{customEvent}}\"></logEvent>"
```

and have everything work. This appears to not be the case.

I tried playing around with a directive that would compile the code based  on the solution in another question ([How to make ng-bind-html compile angularjs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726179/how-to-make-ng-bind-html-compile-angularjs-code)) in a jsFiddle, but have been unable to figure out how to get this to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/979mN/473/

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just to be sure, why do you need to build the html in JS ?

Comment: I don't necessarily need to build the html in JS. I have the logEvent directive in use in another place in my application, and wanted re-use it. I am not against changing my approach if I am trying to tackle this problem incorrectly.

Comment: Then, could you use the directive directly instead of ng-bind-html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what was wrong, here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1sLL8h17/1/) :

Instead of this

```
 Hi There! <complex value='{{$scope.value}}'></complex>
```

Put this :

```
 Hi There! <complex value='value'></complex>
```

Why ?
In an angular directive when you pass a parameter it will be interpreted by angular. You need to pass it like this value="somethingAngularWillInterpret".

When angular interpret a value, he will use the scope service to find this value. You don't have to use $scope into your html.

Last point : Using {{}} is for making angular interpret codes. In HTML text elements "value" mean the text "value". {{value}} means "show the value of the var "value""

Hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass `value` without interpolating it (also without scope):

```
$scope.textVar = "Hi There! <complex value='value'></complex>"
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wjcsdgq/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you r passing value from your controller directly like this

```
$scope.value = { hello: "Hello", world: "World!" };
$scope.textVar = "Hi There! <complex value='{{$scope.value}}'></complex>";
```

you can just remove scope from directory

```
scope: {
      value: '='
    },
```

working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/979mN/474/)