# Render Facebook's embed added dynamically

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I am trying to render Facebook's embed. I am using ng-repeat. The problem is when added a new embed in array.

Below is the plunkr file I made as an example.

Thanks.

http://plnkr.co/edit/pzUUL9n4MQ7JMhCO9l3A?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="embed in arr_embed">
 <div ng-bind-html="embed | htmlEmbed"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726179/how-to-make-ng-bind-html-compile-angularjs-code

Comment: the problem is ... template include the text '<script>' and not executing :/