# How to show angular data model as HTML?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a data-model that needs to be converted or show up as html. Right now it just shows up as text.

html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ornamentFigures" class="ornament-item">
    <label for="ornament-{{item.id}}">{{item.svg}}</label>
    <input type="radio" id="ornament-{{item.id}}" name="ornament-radio" />
</div>
```

controller

```
$scope.ornamentFigures = ornamentFigures.ornamentFigures;
```

service

```
MyApp.service('ornamentFigures', function(){

    this.ornamentFigures = [
        {id:'03', name:'wit', svg:'<svg></svg>'},
        {id:'03', name:'wit', svg:'<svg></svg>'},
        {id:'03', name:'wit', svg:'<svg></svg>'},
    ];

    return this;
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [With ng-bind-html-unsafe removed, how do I inject HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make ng-bind-html compile angularjs code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726179/how-to-make-ng-bind-html-compile-angularjs-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)?

Replace:

```
<label for="ornament-{{item.id}}">{{item.svg}}</label>
```

With:

```
<label for="ornament-{{item.id}}" ng-bind-html="item.svg"></label>
```

Also include `ngSanitize` in your module and include "angular-sanitize.js" in your application as per [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

Instead of binding the data as is, it will render as html.  Keep in mind there are security implications to this.  You might want to try a different way if you can.

Comment: I tried it for some reason it doesn't work with ng-repeat. It just shows up like this: <label for="ornament-01" ng-bind-html="item.svg" class="ng-binding"></label>

Comment: Try simply `ng-bind="item.svg"`.  That should work right away in the ng-repeat, but not render as html.  I updated my answer to say that you need to include ngSanitize in your module in order to use ng-bind-html.

Comment: Ah oke, it works now by including the ngSanitize. I'll try another way when I find it thanks!