# Bind ng-click in ng-bind-html :: Binding Angular attributes in the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a HTML code I am dynamically changing based on the navigation stack. I am using `ng-bind-html` to insert the string containing the code into the view. Now I need to be able to input the ng-click attribute into the view too. Everything is OK except the `ng-click` attribute does not get injected and hence I am unable to quickly navigate in the breadcrumbs.

Here is the HTML I am passing to the view:

```
$scope.breadcrumbs = $scope.breadcrumbs + '&nbsp;<i class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i>&nbsp;' + '<span ng-click="goToLevel(pathLength)" class="browse-breadcrumbs-link">' + $scope.title + '</span>';
```

The class gets applied but the ng-click attribute gets simply ignored. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: You should concider creating some directive for handling breadcrumbs.

Comment: @JoãoColucas How would that work? I have an n number of levels I can go into, the data is created dynamically from the server so I cannot know in advance how many strings I will need.

Comment: I'm sure it would be way easier if you just pushed next breadcrumb into i.e. array and repeat through the said array to generate nice breadcrumbs

Comment: @maurycy I will give it a try

Comment: @maurycy Ah yes, so simple, I am an expert on creating complicated solutions :P thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ng-bind-html compile angularjs code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726179/how-to-make-ng-bind-html-compile-angularjs-code)

Comment: @maurycy All solved now, easy peasy, thanks!

Comment: Great, happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `ng-bind-html` API you will come to know that it only parse the html & append it as text to the DOM using `element.text`. The html has added will not have any compile'd angular DOM. It will work as normal markup.

I'd suggest your own directive to handle breadcrumb stuff by putting it on `breadcrumb` element. So that you can get control over that DOM inside directive link function. After creating your breadcrumb html you need to compile that html first and then append it to `breadcrumb` DOM using `$compile` service.

**Code**

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
   //you code would something like below..
   //create an html
   scope.breadcrumbs = scope.breadcrumbs + '&nbsp;<i class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i>&nbsp;' + '<span ng-click="goToLevel(pathLength)" class="browse-breadcrumbs-link">' + $scope.title + '</span>';
   element.empty();
   element.append($compile(scope.breadcrumbs)(scope))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the syntax of breadcrumbs it looks like it can be replaced with simple `ng-repeat` and leaving html for the view layer i.e.

#### controller

```
  $scope.breadcrumbs.push(newCrumb)
```

where newCrumb would be an object with all the information you need

#### view

```
<span ng-repeat="crumb in breadcrumbs">
  &nbsp;<i class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i>
  &nbsp;<span ng-click="goToLevel(pathLength)" class="browse-breadcrumbs-link">{{crumb.title}}</span>
</span>
```