# ng-repeat inside $sce.trustAsHtml

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass a ng-repeat inside the

```
$sce.trustAsHtml("<p ng-repeat='panel in panels'>{{panel.displayName}}</p>")
```

Is this the right way to do it? I would like to use the result assigned to ng-bind-html.

Comment: No its not..because `ng-repeat` directive will not get evaluated. `ng-bind-html` only sanitize the html and add it to the content of element.

Comment: @PankajParkar can you suggest a good way to do that? I want to implement that functionality

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29994559/2435473) to implement your goal

Comment: thanks a lot..that helped