# How to insert HTML along with onclick function into view in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, escaping, html-sanitizing

I am trying to render html into my view and i want to insert a function call inside this html but not getting any idea how i can do this. Here is my javascript:

```
        angular.forEach($scope.patients, function (patient) {
         tableRow = tableRow + [
             '<div data-ng-click="popup("+patient+")">',
                 '<div class="name-container">+patient.name+</div>',

             '</div>'].join('');
    });
    $scope.renderHTML =$sce.trustAsHtml(tableRow);

    $scope.popup = function(patient) {
    ...

};
```

HTML:

```
  <div data-ng-bind-html="renderHTML">
             </div>
```

Is it possible to add patient object in popup() function using this way ?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:
$eval helps to evaluate different angular expressions

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="$eval(renderHTML)">
             </div>
```

JS

It may help you,

```
angular.forEach($scope.patients, function (patient) {
         tableRow = tableRow + [
             '<div data-ng-click="popup("'+patient+'")">',
                 '<div class="name-container">'+patient.name+'</div>',

             '</div>'].join('');
    });
    $scope.renderHTML =$sce.trustAsHtml(tableRow);

    $scope.popup = function(patient) {
    ...

};
```

You are passing patient object in popup function, I think it may not work. If it doesn't work try using `JSON.stringify`

Refer following link for more information [How to make ng-bind-html compile angularjs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726179/how-to-make-ng-bind-html-compile-angularjs-code)

**Suggestion:**

Try to use ng-repeat directive in the place of angular.forEach. I think you can achieve your requirement easily by using ng-repeat, for reference:

```
 <div ng-repeat="patient in patients">
        <div data-ng-click="popup(patient)">
           <div class="name-container">patient.name</div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**MODIFIED:**

> Try this

```
angular.forEach($scope.patients, function(value,key){
         tableRow = tableRow + [
             '<div data-ng-click="popup("'+patients[key]+'")">',
                 '<div class="name-container">'+patients[key].name+'</div>',

             '</div>'].join('');
    });
    $scope.renderHTML =$sce.trustAsHtml(tableRow);

    $scope.popup = function(patient) {
    ...

};
```

Comment: Well i have a more than 2k records and data-ng-repeat make it very slow so that i am testing another way to render this list..