# How to compile dynamic content in Angular UI tabs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/IY1HqWRDHcK3BqUiMRKD?p=preview) I have an Angular UI tab that displays HTML content. Each content has a `div` containing an `ng-click` directive, that doesn't work. Most likely the directive needs to be compiled? how to achieve that?

HTML

```
  <uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}">
      <div ng-bind-html="tab.content"></div>
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize']);

app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

     $scope.tabs = [
       { title:'title 1', content:'<div ng-click="click(1)" id="id1">111</div>' },
       { title:'title 2', content:'<div ng-click="click(2)" id="id2">222</div>' }
     ];


     $scope.click = function(i){
       alert(i);
     };

});
```

Comment: it would be better if you didn't store template content in variables, and instead used `ng-template`.

Comment: I just need to define a div in the tab and later I will add dynamically more content, that's why I cannot use a template

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer, compile using this directive:

```
app.directive('dynamic', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
                element[0].innerHTML = html;
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726179/how-to-make-ng-bind-html-compile-angularjs-code)

Answer (score 0):

Instead change the implementation.

```js
var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize']);

app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

     $scope.tabs = [
       { title:'title 1', content: {id:1, label: 111} },
       { title:'title 2', content: {id:2, label: 222} }
     ];


     $scope.click = function(i){
       alert(i);
     };

});
```

```html
   
<uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}">
      <div ng-click="click(tab.content.id)" id="id{{tab.content.id}}">{{tab.content.label}}</div>
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
```

---

Other best way is to use directives.

```html
<uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}">
      <my-directive my-click="click(tab.content.id)" my-content="tab.content"</directive-x>
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
```