# Ng-repeat & Ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind-html

Does ng-repeat works inside ng-bind-html?

Where res2 is the StaticPage content.  And res is a json file.  Notice that I can get the variables from the scope (also print the json Array) but not possible to iterate with the ng-repeat.

Home Controller:

```
$rootScope.usefulContent = res;
$rootScope.staticContent = $interpolate(res2)($rootScope);
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="homeCtrl" class="headerSize" id="staticPage">
<div ng-bind-html="staticContent"></div>
</div>
```

Static Page:

```
<div class="container content-home">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in usefulContent | groupBy: 'Order'">
                        {{key}}
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group" data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in usefulContent | groupBy: 'Order'">
                        <li class="list-group-item">{{key}}
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item child" data-ng-repeat="link in value">
                                    {{ link.SUBSECTION }}
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                Col 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Order": 1,
    "SECTION": "HR",
    "SUBSECTION": "Administration",
  },
  {
    "Order": 1,
    "SECTION": "HR",
    "SUBSECTION": "Self Service",
  }
]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which ng-repeat is not working?

Comment: Also, can you post the JSON you are trying to iterate through?

Comment: Done, and both ng-repeat are not working

Comment: You say both ng-repeat are working, there are 3 ng-repeat in your html

Comment: Can you post a static example of what you want your bootstrap `list-group` to look like?

Comment: not sure what you mean I posted it, the idea is to the StaticPage.html have it in a DB to be possible to edit it and avoid having to re publish de app
None of the ng-repeat works, if I put a simple ng-repeat=[1,2,3,4], it doesnt work neither. But if I print some variable from the scope works, and for example if I use other directive like ng-if also works, but ng-repeat no case.

Comment: what I meant was please include the expected output of what you want AFTER the `ng-repeat` has run. It's difficult to work out exactly what you want the page to look like. 

I'm confused because you have `ng-repeat="(key, value) in usefulContent`, then you are expecting key value pairs yet `usefulContent` is an array of objects so you will not get key value pairs you will get an object.

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't compile the html you included automatically.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726179/how-to-make-ng-bind-html-compile-angularjs-code) explains how to do it.